# How do you use Google Play discount in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go, google-play-games

I've received multiple notifications from Google Play telling me that I can get 3$ off an in app purchase in Pokemon Go. It's literally from Pokemon Go app notifications, so I click it and click apply and it just opened the Pokemon app, nothing else.

Anyone found a way to use the "discount"?

Comment: Could it be that in the step before you are going to pay, this discount is taken into account? I cannot try it, as I don't have this discount. And try on your own risk, before you buy it without discount :)

Answer (score 3):

I've used these a couple times. To use it, you'll need to go to the store in Pokemon Go and select something that costs real money instead of Pokecoins. When it brings up methods to pay for your selection, you should be able to see the discount applied there. If it's not applied, tap on the payment methods and you should be able to see it in the list along with any credit cards you have linked and Google Play credits (if you have any). It will cover part of the cost, and the rest will be applied to whatever normal payment method you use.

Comment: If you don't actually have the code/see it, you may need to activate/redeem the code in the Google Play store prior to it, so if you don't see the discount, you can go to Google Play Store -> Play Points -> Use -> Pokemon Go and there should be a $3 coupon

Comment: Also it only applies if you select an item that will cost equal to or more than the coupon, you can't use it to purchase something that cost less than the coupon. And obviously the value of the coupon is not equal to anything, so you're required to spend some money.